# Guitar strings and temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, elasticity, string

I am investigating [Mersenne's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne%27s_laws) with a guitar by varying tension (hanging weights) and string length. Will temperature change (room temperature to ~4°C) effect the frequency noticeably? If so, is the string oscillating differently or is the change due to a variation of the speed of sound? The strings have a free end so the contraction of the string will not increase tension.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The resonance length will change because of the temperature change as well as the speed of sound change.

Comment: Know any useful related formulas?

Answer (score 1):

The speed of sound [according to this chart](http://www.ndt-ed.org/EducationResources/HighSchool/Sound/tempandspeed.htm) would change as much as 330.4/358.0 = 8% .
The air behaves closely to an ideal gas, therefore this kind of change would hardly change the pitch, let alone be noticeable to a human ear.

However the change in temperature would effect the stiffness and length of the string dramatically, this depends on [what material you are using.
Look at the difference of length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion#Thermal_expansion_coefficients_for_various_materials) vs temperature.

Since you are using weights, your stress is not going to change, and the tension would remain the same.

Try using this equation:

[image: Equation of frequency of a string]

But this is not the full picture, since you are actually using an open string with dampening. Though with those speeds it should be approximated to a closed string.

You can try using:
$$f_open = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{T}{m/2}}}{2L} \cdot constant$$

And tune the constant to fit your current parameter space.

[Source with calculator](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/string.html)
(The calculator though would not work in your case because one of your ends is open).

Answer (score 0):

The frequency does not depend on the medium of propagation. The wavelength does. That is why I think that the temperature influences on the frequency of oscillations only due to changes in elasticity or length of the string.